# Method access control and POD

Tags: c++, c++11

According to [the docs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/StandardLayoutType)

> All non-static data members have the same access control

and [this piece of code](http://ideone.com/r9EXg0)

```
#include <iostream>

struct KO
{
    int a;
private:
    int b;
};

struct OK
{
    void Foo() { a = 42; }
private:
    void Bar() { a = 43; }

    int a;
};

int main() {
    // your code goes here
    std::cout << std::boolalpha;
    std::cout << std::is_pod<KO>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::is_pod<OK>::value << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

a structure is not a POD when data members have different access control, but no mention is done about function members, and they actually are PODs despite having different access controls.

Why is that ? What is the difference between data and function access controls in C++ structs ?

Comment: It gives freedom to compiler writers to organise data with different access controls differently. What the original rationale for that was I cannot tell you - probably extremely historic (back to the days when c++ was basically a pre-processor for c).

Comment: PODness is about layout, not access. Only non-static data members participate in layout. (And the layout is grouped by access level and indeterminate across different access levels.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions don't play a significant role because they are not stored within the object. A member function is just a plain function with a implicit parameter (*this*) inserted by the compiler. Only non-static **data** members are laid in memory as part of the object.

As the docs mention, one of the requirements of a POD is that access control for all non-static data members is the same. Even though your `OK` struct has a private integer, it's the only one, so that's not a problem. But if you add a public `int b;` you should see the same result as for your `KO` type (regardless of the `Bar` and `Foo` functions).